# Writing geometric series formula?

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

This is my formula $t_n=8*\frac{3}{2}^{n-1} $  for this geometric series `8,12,18,27...` My book has this formula for the same series: $t_n=\frac{16}{3}(\frac{3}{2})^n$. I tried both and they work, so how do I arrive at the form my book has presented? My book's equation doesn't follow the normal geometric series equation so I am a bit lost.

Answer (score 2):

$8\cdot \frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{2}\cdot \left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^{n-1}=?$.

Notice $\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{3}{2}=1$ so I did not change the value.

Comment: So then what's the purpose of this, and why did they choose this notation over the other?

Comment: I guess because they want the power to be $n$?

Comment: I don’t see how this gets to what my book has.

Comment: $8\cdot \frac{2}{3}=\frac{16}{3}$ and $\frac{3}{2}\cdot \left (\frac{3}{2}\right )^{n-1}= \left (\frac{3}{2}\right )^{n}$.